# Ajax loaded form elements for post-edit screen

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I want to load some form elements for a custom post type's edit screen via AJAX.

What's the best practice to implement this?

Should I use this algorithm?

> Hook an action to `admin_menu` to
>
> > detect the request from AJAX client (via `x-requested-with`),
> >
> > clean the buffer (via `ob_clean`),
> >
> > output the requested element, and exit.
>
> Request `wp-admin/post-new.php` from AJAX client